# How to get post-data after sending the https.request using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get options and post-data of the request object that were added before sending the request

For reports, it would be more useful to use one state of the data that have the results of the request and response

```
function request(options, postData) {
    const Module = protocol==='https:' ? https : http;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = Module.request(options);
        req.on('response', resolve);
        req.on('error', reject);
        postData && req.write(postData);
        req.end();
    });
}

const options = { ... };
const postData = { ... };

request(options, postData)
.then(response => {

    // How to get this data?
    console.log(response.req.options);
    console.log(response.req.postData);

})
.catch(console.error);
```

Comment: You need to use `resolve` and `reject` within your promise in order to get data with `then` and `catch`. Like `resolve(req);`.

Comment: Oh of course. Thanks, buddy